# Export specified text in CSV to HTML

Tags: php, html, html-table, import-from-csv

I have a CSV file with this information: [CSV Link](http://ubm2014.no/HTML/testserver.csv)

As you can see it is a lot of data here, and I am asking if it is possible to convert some of the data to a table in HTML. Like if I only would convert the data in "Kamp" "Række" "Navn1" "Navn2" and "Resultat"

Would it be possible or do I need to convert everything to html?
I have not access to edit the CSV file because it automatically imports new data.

Hopefully there are someone with a gifted mind here who has the solution.
If anything is not clear then please ask me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start from here, you'll have the data of each row inside a php array, then you can echo what you want inside html.

```
<table>
<?php 
     $handle=fopen('filename.csv', r);
     while($data=fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ';', '"')){?>
           <tr>
               <td><?php echo $data[0];?></td>
               <td><?php echo $data[1];?></td>
               <td><?php echo $data[2];?></td>
               <td><?php echo $data[3];?></td>
           </tr>
<?php }
     fclose($handle);
?>
</table>
```

But I see you have too many " in your csv file.